# Not allowed to use <br> tag inside h2 element?

Tags: html, css

I got an error from HTML validator: "End tag h2 seen, but there were open elements."

And it is caused by this code:

```
<h2 class="heading heading--sub feature-box__heading">Ärikinnisvara- <br> haldus</h2>
```

Problem is that I got 3 errors for the exact same thing (I am using the same solution in 3 different places) and I really need it to break line after "-". What would be another way to solve this problem if I want to write valid HTML?

Comment: Close your `<br>` tag: `<br />`

Comment: I suspect you're using a HTML validator in XHTML mode, which requires the markup to comply with the XML rules, namely that all no-closing-tag-necessary elements are of the form `<element />`.

Comment: I am using this HTML validator: https://validator.w3.org, settings are validate full document and doctype: detect automatically

Comment: My HTML 5 test case against that validator, with your h2 copy-pasted, passes validation.

Comment: Can you check by this url and not direct input, please? URL: http://kinnisvaraabc.herokuapp.com/ (I know about other errors and I already fixed them).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<span>` inside your `<h2>` and make **css** for breaking like this:

```css
h2 span {
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<h2>This is h1 title -<span>span tag</span></h2>
```

Comment: Line break works the same way with this, but I am still getting the exact same error from w3 validator.

Comment: @KristjanRanna now i'm check this code in W3C: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>test<span>inside span</span></h2>
</body>
</html>` and no have any errors.

Comment: Can you please test this url with validator? URL: http://kinnisvaraabc.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your br tag in order for this to work. br works in every element, except those we are all sure don't work, such as !DOCTYPE html or script or even style. `<br />`